# How can I repeat a query with multiple columns N times with a join who only take ONE column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(Opgivelser!A:E; "select D,A,B where E = TRUE");"Vælg fordybelsesområder")
```

for this:

[image]

And it works as intended but I also want to repeat it i.e twice or based on a cells value i.e D2.

I have tried to to use this:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(","; IFERROR(REPT(IFERROR(QUERY(Opgivelser!A:E; "select D,A,B where E = TRUE"); "Vælg fordybelsesområder") & ","; D2))); ",")))
```

But that one prompts an error about ONE row/column.

What will I have to change? Or is there an even more simple or logical syntax for this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `want to repeat it i.e twice or based on a cells value`?

Comment: I want to "run" the query twice. But some for the sake of flexibility I want to define that from a cell, i.e. D2.

Comment: Run twice means run from two different cells? And define that from a cell means that you replace "Vælg fordybelsesområder" through a cell reference?

Comment: @ziganotschka Sorry if I was not being more specific. I will try harder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♠"&
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&IFERROR(QUERY(Opgivelser!A:E; 
 "select D,A,B where E = TRUE"); "Vælg fordybelsesområder"))
 ;;9^9));;9^9); F1); "♠")); "♦"))
```

[image: 0]